# Trying to get the public IP from C#

Tags: c#, parsing, ip

I'm trying to get the public IP of the user but i get this error:

```
    System.Net.IPAddress.InternalParse(string, bool)
    System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(string)
    Test.Form1.GetPublicIp(string) in Form1.cs
    Test.Form1.button2_Click(object, System.EventArgs) in Form1.cs
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(System.EventArgs)
    System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(System.EventArgs)
    System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message, System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons, int)
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    ...
```

I use this code:

```
static System.Net.IPAddress GetPublicIp(string serviceUrl = "https://wtfismyip.com/text")
        {
            return System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(serviceUrl));
        }
```

Anything that might help?
thanks.

Comment: use `DownloadString(serviceUrl).Trim()`

Comment: Also, why was i down-voted? :(

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that that URL you set in there it returns the next `"192.168.1.1\n"` as you see there is a `\n` at the end, which is causing your issue, if you add a `.Replace("\n","")` it works fine.

```
return System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(serviceUrl).Replace("\n", ""));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
static string GetIPAddress()  
{  
    String address = "";  
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");  
    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())  
    using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))  
     {  
        address = stream.ReadToEnenter code hered();  
     }  
     int first = address.IndexOf("Address: ") + 9;  
     int last = address.LastIndexOf("</body>");  
     address = address.Substring(first, last - first);  
     return address;  
}
```

Check out [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-get-public-ip-address-using-c-sharp1) for further detail